# how can I parse a JSON string in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, json

How can I parse this JSON string using the TJSONObject object?

```json
{
  "status":"OK",
  "num_results":"2",
  "results":[
    {
      "title":"",
      "quantity":"",
      "cook_time":"",
      "level":"",
      "master_ingr":"",
      "sub_ingr":"",
      "cook1":"",
      "cook2":"",
      "cook3":"",
      "cook4":"",
      "cook5":"",
      "cook6":"",
      "cook_tip1":"",
      "cook_tip2":"",
      "cook_tip3":"",
      "cook_tip4":"",
      "cook_tip5":"",
      "cook_tip6":""
    },
    {
      "title":" ",
      "quantity":"",
      "cook_time":"",
      "level":"",
      "master_ingr":"",
      "sub_ingr":"",
      "cook1":"",
      "cook2":"",
      "cook3":"",
      "cook4":"",
      "cook5":"",
      "cook6":"",
      "cook_tip1":"",
      "cook_tip2":"",
      "cook_tip3":"",
      "cook_tip4":"",
      "cook_tip5":"",
      "cook_tip6":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You parse it using the [`TJSONObject.Parse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Parse) method...

Comment: @J...: Actually you use the [`TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue) method instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, indeed.  I confess I spent about 7 seconds typing that...the link is on the same manual page. The question left me poorly motivated, I suppose.

Comment: The question shows no effort at all. It really should be downvoted heavily, and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue) method:

```
class function ParseJSONValue(const Data: string; UseBool: Boolean = False): TJSONValue; overload; static;
```

For example:

```
var
  S: string;
  JObj: TJSONObject;
begin
  S := ...;
  JObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S) as TJSONObject;
  try
    ...
  finally
    JObj.Free;
end;
```